# C# Change specific lines in file

Tags: c#, file-handling

I have a text file containing some information that I want to edit. The file looks something like this:

```
id: 31
name: Anna
profession: Doctor
```

I can read that entry with a `StreamReader`, and present it in my application. I then want the user to be able to change the `name` and `profession` of an entry, so I'd like to edit these specific rows to the new values, while keeping `id` intact (in my real code, there's not just a few rows, but a lot of rows where only some should be changed). So, for example, I want the file, at the end of my operation, to look like this.

```
id: 31
name: Emma
profession: Programmer
```

However, I also have to take into account that sometimes the rows don't exist beforehand. For example, before editing `Anna` to `Emma`, it's not certain that she had a profession, the file could have looked like this:

```
id: 31
name: Anna
```

And in that case, I want to add the line `profession: Programmer`to the end there.

I tried using a `FileStream`with `ReadWrite` access, that I give to a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWriter`, but then I found no way of changing or replacing a line of text, only reading it and writing a new identical line while keeping the old.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    bool idExists = false;
    bool nameExists = false;
    bool tagsExist = false;

    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("id:"))
            idExists = true;
        else if (line.StartsWith("name:"))
        {
            nameExists = true;
            line = $"name: {entryToSave.Name}";
            writer.WriteLine(line); // Will write an additional line and not replace
        }
        else if (line.StartsWith("profession:"))
        {
            professionExists = true;
            line = $"profession: {entryToSave.Profession}";
            writer.WriteLine(line); // Will write an additional line and not replace
        }
    }

    if (!idExists)
        writer.WriteLine($"id: {generatedId}");
    if (!nameExists)
        writer.WriteLine($"name: {entryToSave.Name}");
    if (!professionExists)
        writer.WriteLine($"profession: {entryToSave.Profession}");
}
```

I also tried using `File.ReadAllLines`, loop through the lines, and then write back all the lines to the file, only modifying the lines that were to be modified. However, I don't have access to the file through `File.WriteAllLines` for some reason that I don't understand, as a `StreamWriter` has access. Code:

```
var previousData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
var newData = new List<string>();
bool idExists = false;
bool nameExists = false;
bool professionExists = false;

for (int i = 0; i < previousData.Length; i++)
{
    var line = previousData[i];

    if (line.StartsWith("id:")
        idExists = true;
    else if (line.StartsWith("name:")
    {
        nameExists = true;
        line = $"name: {entryToSave.Name}";
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith("profession:"))
    {
        professionExists = true;
        line = $"profession: {entryToSave.Profession}";
    }

    newData.Add(line);
}

if (!idExists)
    newData.Add($"id: {generatedId}");
if (!nameExists)
    newData.Add($"name: {entryToSave.Name}");
if (!professionExists)
    newData.Add($"profession: {entryToSave.Profession}");

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newData.ToArray()); // Access denied
```

How is this most easily achieved, without file streams interfering with each other?

Comment: I just found out myself now that the reason why I can't do File.WriteAllLines is not that the file is busy, access is denied anyway for some reason, that I don't know how to solve. I'll edit my question.

Comment: If you found my solution helpful I'd be very appreciative if you'd mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I forgot! Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already presented the data to the user in entries, enabling the user to edit `name` and `profession`, you could just read the file, get the ID and fill the remainder of the file with the value of the entries. The following is an example console application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filePath = "test.txt";

    // Simulated input from user 
    // these should come from entries in the application?
    var name = "Foo"; 
    var profession = "Bar";

    var personData = new PersonData(); // class declared below

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("id:"))
                personData.ID = line;
        }
    } // Now reader and filestream is closed, file is available again.


    // You don't specify what you would like to happen if personData.ID is null, 
    // so I make an assumption the generatedId is what you'd like to use.
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(personData.ID)
        personData.ID = $"id: {generatedId}"; 

    // Add the data from the entries
    personData.Name = $"name: {name}";
    personData.Profession = $"profession: {profession}";

    File.Delete(filePath); // remove the file

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(personData.ID);
        writer.WriteLine(personData.Name);
        writer.WriteLine(personData.Profession);
    }
}
private class PersonData
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

Now you just have to find out how to get access to the file if you're having permission problems.

Comment: Reading from one file, deleting it and writing to a new one indeed was the simplest way to do it!